# Constructing triangle $\triangle ABC$ given median $AM$ and angles $\angle BAM, \angle CAM$

Tags: geometry, triangles, geometric-construction

> Constructing triangle $\triangle ABC$ given median $AM$ and angles $\angle BAM, \angle CAM$

I start with the median $AM$. Since $\angle BAM, \angle CAM$ are known I can construct them. So I have point $A$, line segment $AM$ and $2$ rays starting from A where $\angle BAM, \angle CAM$ are those from the hypothesis. If only I could find a way to construct a line where $BM = MC$ I would be done. I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: did you tried draw a circle with center in $M$ ?

Comment: I mean, the diameter must to be your side $BC$. $B,C$ must be the intersection of the circunference with the rays, think on it.

Comment: Yes, how does it help me, though? Suppose I have a circle with center $M$ and radius $|AM|$ it's not onto $B$  or $C$ since $\angle  BAC$ is not a right angle.

Comment: ok, i'll answer your question. let me draw. please wait

Comment: I trough use some Euler Line to solve this but i'm mistaken, here you have the fast answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Solution]

The black lines are your dates. at first we draw green lines which are parallels to the rays in the point $M$, so we get the points $J,K$. with center in $J$ and radio $AJ$ we draw the red circle. similar with the point $K$ so we get the purple points $B,C$ and the segment $BC$ is your goal.

Comment: What program did you use for drawing?

Comment: its name is geogebra

Answer (score 5):

The symmetric of $C$ with respect to $M$ is $B$, hence in order to find our triangle it is enough to intersect the $AB$ line with the symmetric of the $AC$ line with respect to $M$.

[image]